# python enviando email com varios anexos

Tags: python, python-3.x, envio-de-email, smtp, mime-type

Boa tarde,

Sou novo em programação especialmente em python e estou tentando enviar todos os arquivos de uma determinada pasta como anexo em um email. E garimpando na internet consegui chegar a esse código que estou usando:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication

smtp_ssl_host = "smtp.exemplo.com"
smtp_ssl_port = 465

from_addr = "Meu Email"
to_addrs = ["Destinatario1", "Destinatario2"]

username = "Meu Email"
password = "minha Senha"
pdfName = "caminho/202008/*.pdf"

message = MIMEMultipart()
message["From"] = from_addr
message["To"] = ", ".join(to_addrs)
message["Subject"] = "Testando o envio de anexos pdf pelo python"
raw = message.as_string()
body = MIMEText("Exemplo de envio com anexo PDF")
message.attach(body)

fp = open(pdfName, 'rb')
anexo = MIMEApplication(fp.read(), _subtype="pdf")
fp.close()
anexo.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=pdfName)
message.attach(anexo)

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_ssl_host, smtp_ssl_port)
server.login(username, password)
server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addrs, raw)
server.quit()
```

Eu consigo enviar o email, mas o anexo não envia, além disso tenho o problema que a cada mês o nome da pasta altera seguindo esse padrão "caminho/202008", "caminho/202009" e assim por diante.
Então precisava que o caminho da pasta mudasse de acordo com o ano e mês e enviasse todo o conteúdo da pasta como anexo. Mas só consegui realizar o envio do email sem anexo, queria saber como anexar todo o conteúdo e mudar a pasta de acordo com a data do computador.

Muito obrigado a quem puder me dar uma luz nessa questão.

Comment: Consegue fazer um teste de mesa que descreva a execução deste código? Parece-me que está tentando utilizá-lo sem entendê-lo por completo. Talvez o teste de mesa te ajude nisso.

Comment: De fato me considero ainda como leigo, estou estudando a respeito então diria que compreendo parte do código a cima, pelo acho que compreendo. Mas não sei se conseguiria executar um teste do tipo, mas vou tentar aqui pra ver. Na realidade ainda estou bem no começo no que diz respeito a python e programação

Comment: A questão do nome da pasta, se for um número sequencial é só você encapsular o envio dentro de um for, por exemplo, e utilizar uma variável que incrementa em 1 unidade a cada repetição

Comment: entendi, eu tinha pensado em criar um objeto data pra pegar o mês e o ano atual e converter em string para usar no nome da pasta, por que o nome da pasta só mudaria quando a cada fim de mês. Será que resolveria assim? pensei nisso mais não sei se geraria algum problema pois não testei isso ainda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao fazer `pdfName = "caminho/202008/*.pdf"` você não está buscando todos os arquivos PDF do seu diretório, mas sim apenas um arquivo que possui o nome `*.pdf`, que provavelmente nem existe.

Para buscar de fato todos os arquivos PDF do diretório, recomendo que leia sobre a classe `pathlib.Path`, em particular o método `glob`:

```
from pathlib import Path

date = '202008'
directory = Path('caminho') / date
pdfs = directory.glob('*.pdf')
```

Depois disso, faça um laço de repetição que itere sobre a lista de arquivos anexando-os um a um no seu e-mail.

Para pegar o ano/mês corrente, sugiro utilizar o pacote `datetime`.

Comment: Entendi, imaginei que poderia tentar alterar o nome da pasta usando o datetime.Vou tentar implementar dessa maneira e vou dar uma olhada nessa classe pathlib. Obrigado